# how to change stack protection via syscalls without parameters

Tags: c, linux-kernel, x86, system-calls, exploit

This is a little bit strange question. I am trying to find a syscall that allowed to execute code on the stack without parameters on i386. I am doing ctf and I success to find a way to call syscall and control eax and have full control on the stack (with argv so just pointer to my strings). now I am jumping to the vdso (thats all the code in the program no dll's or anything else) to run a syscall that will allowed stack execution. but I go on the man page over and over and didn't found something I can use.

`$uname -r 4.4.179-0404179-generic`

Comment: There is no explicit syscall for that. It's a blatant security violation and not terribly useful anyway. You might have some luck with `mprotect`. But, if you can do that, you don't need to because you already have full control and can execute any code you want _without_ having to put code on the stack.

Comment: Are syscalls (with or without parameters) that execute user code (on the stack or otherwise) a thing???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no zero-arg Linux system call equivalent to `mprotect(stack_base, stack_size, PROT_WRITE|PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC)`.

Not that I know of, and I wouldn't expect there to be one.  Probably the only use case would be to help attackers, which is the opposite of hardening; normally you can make the stack executable via linker options or any specific pages via `mprotect` with args.  There's no need for a shortcut for that.

There's also not one that can set the `READ_IMPLIES_EXEC` personality for an already-running process, even if you do allow args.  (See *[Using personality syscall to make the stack executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74091159/using-personality-syscall-to-make-the-stack-executable)* - at best it will have an effect after `execve`.)

---

You might be able to use some ROP techniques to get some args set up for `mprotect`, and then return to the code you injected.

Comment: Thank you Peter I think there is more things I could try and didn't think of. I will see what I can do. By the way I am the one who asked this question too lol